# soapUI/Message Broker - Test flows based on SOAP

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, messagebroker

This one may be simple, but can't find it. I understand that flows with SOAP nodes (SOAP Input for example) are exposed as web services in Message Broker. How can I consume them with soapUI?

Answer (score 0):

As you should have a WSDL file specifying your web services in your soap nodes, you should take that WSDL, import it into soapUI, then specify the endpoint to your WMB machine (I think default port is 7080 or something like that). It should be pretty straight forward.